# Prove: symmetric positive matrix multiplied by skew symmetric matrix equals 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My teacher gave me this task as preparation for the exam but I'm stuck and not sure if it's true anymore.

Comment: To get a feel for the problem, you might try the $2 \times 2$ case.  Let $X = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{bmatrix}0&c\\-c&0\end{bmatrix}$.  You'll find that in general, neither $XY = 0$ nor $YX = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to see that the desired result is false is to remember that the identity matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response. I'll try that now.

Comment: Note that the ordinary matrix multiplication will generally not be zero. For example, let the symmetric matrix be the identity matrix; then the product will simply be the skew symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your teacher means [Frobenius product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).
In the context of tensor analysis (e.g. widely used in mechanics, think about $\int \boldsymbol{\sigma}:\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}\Omega$, if you know the weak form of elastostatics), it is a natural inner product for 2nd order tensors, whose coordinates can be represented in matrices.

The result is straightforward
$$A:B = \operatorname{tr}(A^T B) =a_{ij}b_{ij} = -a_{ji}b_{ji} = - A:B \Rightarrow A:B = 0.$$

Comment: You beat me to that. +1

Answer (score 0):

Let J and R be skew symmetric and symmetric matrices. Index notation of these matrices are;

$J_{ij}R_{ij}$=-$J_{ji} R_{ij}$     (1),

since R is symmetric matrix and can be written as $R_{ji}$=$R_{ij}$

Equation 1 becomes,

$J_{ij}$$R_{ij}$=$-J_{ji}$$R_{ji}$, swapping the indices on RHS will give,

$J_{ij}$$R_{ij}$=-$J_{ij}$$R_{ij}$ finally we obtain

$JR=-JR$  $\Rightarrow$  $2JR=0$ and **$JR=0$**

Answer (score 0):

Let **A** be a symmetric matrix and **B** be a skew-symmetric matrix. i.e., $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ and $B_{ij} = -B_{ji}$.

Define: **C** = **AB**

Prove that Tr(**C**) = Tr(**AB**) = 0

$C_{ik} = A_{ij}B_{jk}$

Using the properties above, the following is also true:

$C_{ik} = A_{ij}B_{jk} = A_{ji}(-B_{kj})$

and

$C_{ik} = A_{ij}B_{jk} = -A_{ji}B_{kj}$.

If we multiply through by $\delta_{ik}$:

$\delta_{ik}C_{ik} = \delta_{ik}A_{ij}B_{jk} = -\delta_{ik}A_{ji}B_{kj}$

which yields
$C_{ii} = A_{ij}B_{ji} = -A_{ji}B_{ij}$

$C_{ii} = C_{ii} = -C_{jj}$

Note that $C_{ii}$ and $C_{jj}$ are the same and are both equal to Tr(**C**).

Tr(**C**) = Tr(**C**) = -Tr(**C**)

For a scalar number to be equal to its negative, it must be zero.

$\therefore$ Tr(**C**) = 0

Answer (score -1):

Say $J$ is skew symmetric and $R$ is symmetric and invertible (a strictly positive definite matrix is invertible) .

Then 
$$
J R = ( R^{-1} R ) J R = R^{-1} ( R J R ) = 0
$$
where the last equality follows by properties of skew-symmetric matrices.